# From which file should I copy data to make an img on Rasbian if I want to backup raspberry and retore it

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I saw one highly-voted answer on the net and it goes like this:

> On Linux, you can use the standard dd tool:
>   `dd if=/dev/sdx of=/path/to/image bs=1M`
>   Where /dev/sdx is your SD card.

But I cheked my device there is no /dev/sdx.
Some other says `dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/path/to/image bs=1M`should work fine.
I suppose it has something to do with the version of my raspberry.Mine is the newst Raspbian version.I don't want to break the systems so I just want to make sure the code is right before I run it.So I come here to ask help from those who have tried it before.

This is the situation of my filesystems:

```
~ $ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/root        15G  4.1G  9.5G  31% / 
devtmpfs        214M     0  214M   0% /dev 
tmpfs           218M     0  218M   0% /dev/shm 
tmpfs    218M  4.7M  213M   3% /run 
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock 
tmpfs           218M     0  218M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
/dev/mmcblk0p1   41M   21M   21M  51% /boot 
tmpfs            44M     0 44M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Which file should I choose??
Anybody knows from which file(similiar with /dev/sdx )to copy the data?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think what I was trying to do is to copy the file from machine A while using machine A. Most people's answers on the Internet actually indicates using another machine B to copy the files of machine A.That's why when when I use "df -h",the terminal shows "/dev/root" instead of "/dev/sdX".

Maybe it's because when you read files,the files itself cannot achieve other operations.So I used another machine B and the code "df -h",it shows "/dev/sdX"  successfully.And now I can follow the instructions on the Internet and do the backup.